# How to write polyphonic guitar staff in abc

Tags: guitar

I'm using abctab2ps, v 1.8.17, built from source on iMac running Ventura.

I'm trying to write down a guitar staff in ABC for a friend who doesn't want guitar tab and I'm having a problem with a voice with a dotted rhythm that I can't seem to figure out how to render. Here's the ABC notation for the 3 voices along with two attempts to render the guitar line. The first doesn't understand that I want to top line (the alto's) E to sound as a dotted quarter when the bottom two voices sound as quarters. The second doesn't follow either the 3/2 time designation nor the following / indicator.

The following code snippet will write out 2 4-voice parts, the second with the top three voices empty. The bottom voice in each is the attempt at the guitar voice. the label of the top one is wrong, it should be 'try1'

Is it even possible to do this in ABC?

```
X:1
T:Two tries to render 3 voice polyphony as single guitar staff
M:2/2
L:1/4
H:
K:D
V:A name=alto
z D E3/2 F/ | G F E3/2 G/ | F2 z F|
V:T name=tenor
z B B3/2 D/ | D D B E |D2
V:B name=bass
z G E3/2 D/ | G D E C | D
V:G name=try1
z [GBd] [E3/2B3/2e3/2] [D/df/] | [Gdg] [Ddf] [Ee3/2] [Ce][g/] | [DBf]2 z [Ddf]
V:G name=try2
z [GBd] [E3/2B3/2e3/2] [D/df/] | [Gdg] [Ddf] [Ee3/2] [Ceg/] | % [D2B2f2] z [Ddf]
```